# I'm able to push my image to my private Docker registry but the 2nd image push is refused

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am no MacOS installed Docker Desktop.

I have a private registry in Docker Hub.

I have two Dockerfiles in my project, each for one image. Both images are built successfully:

```
# 1st image
docker build -t myusername/my-app:1.0.3 -f Dockerfile .
```

```
# 2nd image
docker build -t myusername/my-proxy:1.0.0 -f proxy/Dockerfile .
```

On terminal, I firstly login with my docker id `myusername`:

```
$ docker login -u myusername docker.io
Password:
Login Succeeded
```

Then, I push my first image:

```
$ docker push myusername/my-app:1.0.3
The push refers to repository [docker.io/myusername/my-app]
e632ff00a21f: Layer already exists
...
9578c16f3f7c: Layer already exists
3141322c5cdb: Layer already exists
1.0.3: digest: sha256:43c072e10438c545697c54a76f19a41535a9fb0b7cab2a46b737c5dc497587c0 size: 2422
```

The push is successful!

Then I try to push my second image:

```
docker push myusername/my-proxy:1.0.0
The push refers to repository [docker.io/myusername/my-proxy]
c65e7e80b99d: Preparing
abcda12ed2f7: Preparing
...
1222101d19dd: Waiting
...
9e6f810a2aab: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

However the 2nd image push to docker registry is denied.  Why is that? Where could be wrong for my 2nd image push?

Comment: It is a private Docker registry. We have a Team Plan https://www.docker.com/pricing/ , my docker id is under the plan.

Comment: A private registry or private repository on Hub? If it's a private registry, include details on that registry.

Comment: Yes on Docker Hub. Private repository name is `myusername/my-app`.  I can see on `https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/myusername`, the repository is there.

Comment: I more and more feel that it is because I am only allowed to create one repository on Hub private registry for some reason... Because now I changed the tag of my 2nd image to `docker build -t myusername/myapp:my-proxy1.0.0 -f proxy/Dockerfile .`, the image then can be pushed to the same repo as that for the 1st image.

Comment: For an issue specific to Docker Hub, you probably want to go through your support channels, or submit a public feedback: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues